# Symfony2 2.3.7 -Doctrine 2.4.1: ManyToMany relation is not saved to database

Tags: database, symfony, save, many-to-many

The entity clases are GeLdapGrupo and GeMedio. Many-to-many relation created between them.

Tried with ", cascade={"persist"}" and without. I have modified the add and remove elements methods related to the many-to-many relation. Fixtures put data on ge_medio and ge_ldap_grupo tables, but not in ge_ldap_grupo table (which is the many-to-many relation table).

First class:

```
/**
 * GeMedio
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ge_medio")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class GeMedio
{

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GeLdapGrupo", mappedBy="geMedios"
        , cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $geLdapGrupos;

    //...

    /**
     * Add GeMedios
     *
     * @param GeMedio $geMedios
     * @return GeLdapGrupo
     */
    public function addGeMedio(GeMedio $geMedios, $cascade = true)
    {
        $this->GeMedios[] = $geMedios;
        if ($cascade) {
            $geMedios->addGeLdapGrupo($this, false);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove GeMedios
     *
     * @param GeMedio $geMedios
     */
    public function removeGeMedio(GeMedio $geMedios, $cascade = true)
    {
        $this->GeMedios->removeElement($geMedios);
        if ($cascade) {
            $geMedios->removeGeLdapGrupo($this, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
/**
 * GeLdapGrupo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ge_ldap_grupo")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class GeLdapGrupo
{

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GeMedio", inversedBy="geLdapGrupos"
        , cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ge_ldap_medio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_grupo_ldap",
                referencedColumnName="id_grupo_ldap")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_medio",
                referencedColumnName="id_medio")}
     *      )
     */
    private $geMedios;

    //...

    /**
     * Add GeMedios
     *
     * @param GeMedio $geMedios
     * @return GeLdapGrupo
     */
    public function addGeMedio(GeMedio $geMedios, $cascade = true)
    {
        $this->GeMedios[] = $geMedios;
        if ($cascade) {
            $geMedios->addGeLdapGrupo($this, false);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove GeMedios
     *
     * @param GeMedio $geMedios
     */
    public function removeGeMedio(GeMedio $geMedios, $cascade = true)
    {
        $this->GeMedios->removeElement($geMedios);
        if ($cascade) {
            $geMedios->removeGeLdapGrupo($this, false);
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

The updating code is something like:

```
//insert some data in table 1, save element on an array gemedios.
//  Doing $manager->persist($entity);

//insert some data in table 2, save element on an array geldapgrupos.
//  Doing $manager->persist($entity);

foreach ($relations as $relation)
    print_r($relation);
    $gemedio = $gemedios[$relation['id_gemedio']];
    $geldapgrupo = $geldapgrupos[$relation['id_geldapgrupo']];

    //Now we have all the related entities...
    $gemedio->addGeLdapGrupo($grupo);
    //$geldapgrupo->addGeMedio($medio);
    print_r($medio);
    print_r($grupo);
    //$manager->persist($medio);
    //$manager->persist($grupo);
}
$manager->flush();
```

With the print_r I check the data in the output of the fixtures command, and it looks fine (the gegrupo have a related geldapgrupo and the geldapgrupo have the same gegrupo).

The problem is, as said before, that there is no data on the table ge_ldap_grupo.

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: you still need to persist eitherway

Comment: Thanks you.In the mean time I have turned the many-to-many to a one-to-many many-to-one relationship, with a "bridge" entity. In the future, if I have enough time, energy and more information, I will try to try again those now-apparently-faulty many-to-many relationship functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No need to persist either-way, adding a many to many relation can be done only in one direction and it depends on how you have defined the relation: adding can be done only by the parent entity (the owner entity) of the relation, so in your case you must use:

$geldapgrupo->addGeMedio($gmedio);

Symfony doesn't raise an error for this.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association